# Does someone knows the difference between xavier_normal_ and kaiming_normal_?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

Like title. Does someone knows the difference between xavier_normal_ and kaiming_normal_?  Only Xavier have an argument 'gain' more than kaiming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html):

`xavier_normal_`

> Fills the input Tensor with values according to the method described in “Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks” - Glorot, X. & Bengio, Y. (2010), using a normal distribution.

`kaiming_normal_`

> Fills the input Tensor with values according to the method described in “Delving deep into rectifiers: Surpassing human-level performance on ImageNet classification” - He, K. et al. (2015), using a normal distribution.

The given equations are completely different. For more details you'll have to read those papers.